# Cross Domain $.ajax POST to REST Web Service

Tags: java, javascript, cross-domain, http-status-code-302

I have following scenario:

```
App1:
```

My web service hosted on tomcat server :

```
192.168.100.123



App2:
```

Another application which is communicating with this web service is hosted on another machine and server :

```
192.168.100.456
```

REQUEST and RESPONSE HEADER

```
Allow   OPTIONS,POST
Content-Length  511
Content-Type    application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Date    Thu, 02 May 2013 22:53:17 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
----------------------------
Request Headersview source
  Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
  Access-Control-Request-He...  content-type,x-requested-with
  Access-Control-Request-Me...  POST
  Cache-Control no-cache
  Connection    keep-alive
  DNT   1
  Host  192.168.200.164:8080
  Origin    http://192.168.200.157
  Pragma    no-cache
  User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
```

After debugging the whole scenario using firebug I am sure that the issue is regarding cross domain policy. Kindly help me figure the way out of this'

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) refers to status code having **redirection** information. May be the `App2` tried to login to `App1` and it sent back the logged in **URL** back as the response.

Once `App2` receives such a **response**, proably the **redirection URL** out of the response can be extracted and this URL should be **hit again** by `App2`.

Comment: but I am getting empty response'

Comment: did you check response header?